# react-native fetch network request failed on IOS although "allow arbitrary loads" set to YES

Tags: react-native, fetch

Within my `react-native` app, I get network request failed error on IOS simulator after fetching `GET` method. I tried on Android and it worked perfectly. I know that for IOS I need to set Allow Arbitrary Loads to "yes" in info.plist in Xcode,but I did it long time ago. Beside, I have lots of other pages(components) that I fetch requests and I do not live        any problem on these components. I believe maybe it is something related to URL or response.

Here is my `info.plist` file

[image]

Here is the json that I supposed to get as response of fetch GET method.(BTW, I get the supposed response in ANDROID)

[image]

```
const { dispatch } = this.props;
console.log("Whitespot MAPS Props: ",this.props);

url = '-----------------/coordinates?product=1';
requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.props.token
    }
};


dispatch(authActions.checkTokenAndFetch(url, requestOptions))
    .then((data) => {
        console.log("COORDINATES: ",data);
    },
        (error) => {
    console.log("MAP COORDINATES ERROR: ",error);
        })
```

And here is the error I get while running on IOS simulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Beside, arbitrary loads, I also need to give permission directly to my server url in `info.plist` Exception Domains section. So, it works out in this way. Have a good day.

Just like in pic.

[image]